# Airflow Broken DAG error - The version of cryptography does not match the loaded shared object

Tags: cryptography, airflow

Airflow 1.10.12 Seeing this error in the UI:

Broken DAG: [/home/airflow/dags/something.py] The version of cryptography does not match the loaded shared object. This can happen if you have multiple copies of cryptography installed in your Python path. Please try creating a new virtual environment to resolve this issue. Loaded python version: 2.9.2, shared object version: b'2.9'

The dags compile on the machine with no errors, but these messages appear for almost all the dags.

I have also recreated the virtualenv multiple times, but the error persists.

Anyone seen this before?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that a celery host had a scheduler running that was inserting the errors in the database. Stopped the extra scheduler and the messages went away